# Pass List<T> by Value instead of Reference to Task state

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to create a task to print count of List:

```
        List<int> test = new List<int>{1};

        Task t = new Task((o) =>
        {
            List<int> a = (List<int>)o;
            Console.WriteLine(a.Count);
        }, test);

        t.Start();
        t.Wait();
```

above code print number 1, works as expected:

```
1
```

then I clear `List<int> test` before task start :

```
        List<int> test = new List<int>{1};

        Task t = new Task((o) =>
        {
            List<int> a = (List<int>)o;
            Console.WriteLine(a.Count);
        }, test);

        test.Clear();
        t.Start();
        t.Wait();
```

But it print out same number `0`:

```
0
```

it should print the  number 1 like above, I think this is the problem of the `List` have passed as a reference instead of value, How to fix that?

Comment: Please explain the underlying problem you want to fix.

Comment: List<T> is a class, so, it is passed by refference. If you pass a copy of it - use `test.ToList()`

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I simplified my question

Comment: @vasily.sib - no, it's passed by value. But what's passed is the *variable*'s value, not the object it's referencing. It is unfortunate that we have both value/reference types and pass-by-value and pass-by-reference in the language and they're using the same words to mean subtly different things. Pass by reference means that the callee can *(re)assign* the caller's variable, and that's not what's happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a copy of the list using

```
Task t = new Task(action, new List<int>(test));
```

or

```
Task t = new Task(action, test.ToList());
```

This creates separate list instances that are not shared between each task.